# Dotty Plotting all parameters in a dataset (made by monte carlo runs) against one parameter in R

Tags: r

I am not really familiar with coding but I have to do an exercise where I have to plot all parameter values of a Monte Carlo run over the objective function.

Original wording of exercise :

> "*Within R, produce so-called "dotty-plots" by plotting individual parameter values against the Reff values obtained in the 10,000 Monte Carlo runs*".

The columns have each a different parameter name and for each row there is a different value, each parameter has **10000** values.

How can I dotty plot these parameter values over the objective function (which is also included in the data frame)?

Comment: if you share with us a piece of your data i think i can help you.. please, in r, use the function `dput()`, in which the single argument is the variable in your environment, such as `dput(data)`. run the function and copy and paste the output into your question.

Comment: I put my dataset into dput() but I think the output in the console is too big as I only see a part of the values there... Is there another way?

Comment: i guess you can print it into a file with: `writeLines(dput(data), file_path)`. then you open the file and select it all and paste it on your question. you should maybe start another question clarifying it better, using `dput()` and so on..

Comment: Thank you guys but I managed to do the plots with "ggplot(data = mydataset)"